# How to properly add anchor to form element

Tags: 6, forms

I try:

```
         $form['field_profile_club']['anchor'] = array(
           '#value' => '<a name="my_club"></a>',            
         );
```

But my field (field_profile_club) disappear.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the form apis [prefix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#prefix) and [suffix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#suffix) attributes these will allow you to wrap html around your form element.

Comment: No problem, drupals form api is pretty cool once you know all the additional attributes that you can add.